# Robots.txt Error

Tags: seo, robots.txt

При поиске сайта выдает такую ошибку:

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's
>   robots.txt

http://prntscr.com/g79as9 - Google

http://prntscr.com/g79dpp - Код

Comment: Поиске где? У вас robots.txt не валидный.

Comment: В Google.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в *robots.txt* нет директивы **Host**:
Многие роботы не принимают такие файлы.

Comment: И что писать в robots.txt

Comment: Host: callburn.com

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g79fgg Так правильно?

Comment: Лучше в начале файла. Теоретически на одном сервере может крутиться много сайтов с многими доменами, потому сначала читается host, потом для него директивы... И.т.д..

Comment: Ок, спасибо.....

Answer (score 0):

Согласно справке Гугл **[О файлах robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608)**: "*robots.txt – это специальный файл, расположенный в корневом каталоге сайта*". Но на вашем веб-сайте **[отсутствует этот файл](https://callburn.com/en/robots.txt)** - ошибка 404. Корневой каталог - это самый первый каталог/папка вашего веб-сайта.